# Accessing the commandline using C#

Tags: c#, command-line

I need to access the commandline from within a C# application.  I can't find a way to detect mismatched double quotes if I use the "args" parameter.

The application I'm working on the moment has an option to encrypt a string that you pass to it via the commandline.

eg.

```
program.exe -encrypt somestring
```

Results in:

```
EZs/6rWxvJ82+VE8unJ0Xw==
```

Now if the user types in this:

```
program.exe -encrypt somestring extra characters
```

it ignores everything after "somestring" (you can still access the rest of the values through the "args" parameter).

You can workaround this easily using double quotes:

```
program.exe -encrypt "somestring extra characters"
```

And of course if you want to use embedded quotes you can escape them with "\":

```
program.exe -encrypt "somestring \"extra\" characters"
```

The problem occurs when the user inputs something like this:

```
program.exe -encrypt "somestring extra characters
```

or:

```
program.exe -encrypt somestring ex"tra characters
```

The program will completely ignore the double quote, which not be what the user was expecting.  I would like to detect cases like these and inform the user about the mismatched/unescaped quote, otherwise they might end up with an encrypted version of the wrong string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how the command line passes arguments to your C# program. You cannot change that. You can however access the command arguments string as a whole and perform the validation yourself.

[MSDN: Environment.CommandLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it manually: check that either you have only one argument after the `-encrypt` argument, and if not that the next argument starts with double quotes and the last argument ends with double quotes. If none of these happens throw a custom error to the user.

When the next argument after `-encrypt` starts with double quotes and the last argument ends with double quotes build the string yourself using `Array.Copy` or something of that kind.

Comment: The problem is that the quote gets completely ignored.  ie.  It doesn't show up as part of the value in the "args" parameter.

Comment: I see, sorry for not verifying this myself. You can just take all the arguments after `-encrypt` and join them to be the string, telling the user `-encrypt` must come last if you have more arguments to support.